# Why can't my Azure DevOps pipeline load stages?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

The yaml below creates a pipeline. The pipeline functions as expected, except when you attempt to view/skip stages via the Portal. At this point, I get the error message `Unable to load the pipeline's stages.`

When I create a pipeline manually via the Portal, using the same ymlPath as the automatically generated pipeline, I am able to load the pipelines stages.

```
parameters:
  - name: 'branch'
    type: string
    default: 'main'
  - name: 'folderPath'
    type: string
  - name: 'pipelineName'
    type: string
  - name: 'repositoryName'
    type: string
  - name: 'repositoryType'
    type: string
    default: 'tfsgit'
  - name: 'skipFirstRun'
    type: boolean
    default: true
  - name: 'ymlPath'
    type: string
  - name: 'jobName'
    type: string
    default: 'CreatePipeline'
  - name: 'dependsOn'
    type: object
    default: []
  - name: 'displayName'
    type: string
    default: 'Create a Pipeline'
  
jobs:
  - job: '${{ parameters.jobName }}'
    displayName: '${{ parameters.displayName }}'
    dependsOn: '${{ parameters.dependsOn }}'
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-latest
    steps:       
      - script: echo $(System.AccessToken) | az devops login
        displayName: 'Login to DevOps'

      - task: PowerShell@2
        name: 'CreatePipeline'
        displayName: 'Create a Pipeline'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          failOnStderr: true
          script: |
            $pipelineResult = (az pipelines create `
              --name "${{ parameters.pipelineName }}" `
              --repository "${{ parameters.repositoryName }}" `
              --folder-path "${{ parameters.folderPath }}" `
              --repository-type "${{parameters.repositoryType }}" `
              --branch "${{ parameters.branch }}" `
              --skip-first-run "${{ parameters.skipFirstrun }}" `
              --yml-path "${{ parameters.ymlPath}}" `
              --debug `
              | ConvertFrom-Json)

            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=pipelineId;isOutput=true;]$($pipelineResult.id)"
        env:
          SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

1. I have tried running the `az pipeline show` CLI command directly but face policy issues due to my organisation blocking it.
2. I have tried comparing both pipelines (settings etc) in the Portal and they both seem exactly the same.

Comment: Some clues here which boil down to YAML syntax issues or authorisation.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59772222/azure-pipelines-stages-to-run-does-not-work Maybe paste your YAML into a YAML syntax checker. I feel your pain with organisations needlessly locking things down. This might indicate it's authorisation

Comment: I had seen that thread and checked my YAML as a result. I forgot to add this to the thread! Sadly, it states the syntax is valid.

Comment: I have tested with the yaml shared by you, I don't have the same issue when access the pipeline created by the CLI. Would you please share a screenshot to help clarify "when you attempt to view/skip stages via the Portal"? And share a minimum Yaml File that can reproduce this issue. (The yaml file of the pipeline will be created using CLI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My organization recently saw the same issue: we couldn't load our pipeline stages or resources, despite our YAML syntax being fine. I'm not sure if our solution will suit yours, but we found that an empty "Default agent pool for YAML" setting was causing it (seems like a Microsoft bug). To find this setting do the following:

- Navigate to your pipeline and select "Edit"
- Open the kebab menu in the top right and select "Triggers"
- Open the YAML tab, and verify the "Default agent pool for YAML has a value"

I don't believe the value particularly matters. We specify the pool for all our pipeline jobs, so it never gets used. I hope that helps you as it helped us!

Comment: Adding a default agent pool fixed the issue of updating it in Portal. Any clue how to do this by code? `az pipelines create` doesn't seem to have a way of setting the default agent pool?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any way to change that by code. We handle our pipeline creation manually.

Comment: Great, that resolved our issue as well.